# JavaScript built-in language feature or API function to return undefined when referencing a property of undefined in strict mode

Tags: javascript, properties, reference, undefined, typeerror

Is there any JavaScript built-in language feature or API function to return undefined when referencing a property of undefined in strict mode?

e.g.,:

```
undefined.a
```

throws a `TypeError`.

I can define the following `getProperty` function to do what I want, I'd just prefer to use a JavaScript language feature or built-in API function instead of defining my own function:

```
function getProperty(o, key) {return o && o[key];}
getProperty(undefined, 'a');
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will seem tidy enough for you, but you don't need a function - you can just use `&&` as follows:

```
undefined && undefined.a
```

(Because `&&` returns its left-hand operand if it can be converted to `false`, otherwise it returns its right-hand operand.)

Comment: That's a cleaner way to write my getProperty function, but I'd still use a getProperty function (with your code inside it) since getProperty(o, 'a') references o once, whereas o && o.a references o twice, so there's the possibility to accidentally write o && p.a with the later style.  I'm going to update my question with your improved code, though.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I understand your concern, but figured I'd at least mention this just in case. (And I figured at worst you could use this the way you have...)